# JMeter HTTP Request hangs (probably on overloaded network)

Tags: java, http, jenkins, jmeter

I use JMeter tests to check that our applications are running. The tests are run from Jenkins thru ANT `<jmeter>` tag. The problem is, that **JMeter time to time hangs forever** (and Jenkins executor is blocked as still running). In two months (tests are run every 10minutes) just two such hangs occured, but today, two parallel test were stuck simultaneously (within 5minutes, different tests). I do suspect network connection (it is often overloaded and unreliable), but i want the tests to be reliable even in such environment.

Thread dumps of stuck processes are:

```
   [jmeter] "User test 1-1" prio=10 tid=0x00007fd56c43f000 nid=0x2797 runnable [0x00007fd5704e2000]
   [jmeter]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   [jmeter]     at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
   [jmeter]     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:146)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:204)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:177)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:201)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:155)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1649)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:235)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:300)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.followRedirects(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1410)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.resultProcessing(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1481)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.resultProcessing(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:251)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:358)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1088)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1077)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:428)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
   [jmeter]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

and from the second test (this one tests reachability of www.google.com):

```
   [jmeter] "www.google.com 1-1" prio=10 tid=0x0000000000d32000 nid=0x27e8 runnable [0x00007fb9fea54000]
   [jmeter]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   [jmeter]     at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
   [jmeter]     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:146)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:204)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:177)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:201)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:155)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1649)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:235)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:300)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1088)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1077)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:428)
   [jmeter]     at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
   [jmeter]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

I Use `HTTP Request` Sampler with default values:

```
    <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="www.google.cz" enabled="true">
      <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">www.google.cz</stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
      <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
    </HTTPSamplerProxy>
```

No timeout is set, but i experimented that the default timeout is 240s - when i try to `GET` from non-responding site, everything is OK and after 240s JMeter fails the task (as expected).

JMeter version is 2.9 running on a linux machine.

When I asked sysadmin about network, he said that it's was probably overloaded. I cannot reproduce the bug as it's happening so sparse (nor do i have TCP dump).

I think about two possible workarounds:

- Add a timeout to JMeter to kill the problematic thread - **I'm not sure how, any tips?**
- Add a timeout to Jenkins - using [Build-timout plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin)

But **I'd like to solve the problem, not to make workarounds.**
Do you have any suggestions?

Threads are still stuck, can some useful information be extracted from them? I just used `kill -3 $PID` to get Thread dump.

Comment: Are you really using jmeter 1.9 ? This would clearly  be a problem as it's a very old version.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake, actually it's version 2.9 (latest), I'll edit the question. Thank's for your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just add a Response Timeout to HTTP Sampler:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

> Response Timeout : Number of milliseconds to wait for a response.

If you use HTTPClient4, then you may have the following option, add it to httpclient.parameters:

- http.connection.stalecheck

See http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/preference-api.html#HTTP_connection_parameters:

> Determines whether stale connection check is to be used. Disabling stale connection check may result in slight performance improvement at the risk of getting an I/O error when executing a request over a connection that has been closed at the server side.

Comment: I'll definitely add a timeout value to HTTP Sampler (it was a mistake to omit it), but as I wrote, I'm not sure if it helps as some default timeout to 240s is used in JMeter, when site is not responding (i've check that experimentally). I was hoping that I'm not alone facing similar problem and some other solution can be found.

Comment: There is not default timeout in JMeter. If any timeout it would come from HTTPClient 3 or 4 or Java implementation. I updated my answer with a new configuration parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your help and clarification about timeouts. I've updated my tests and I hope that the problem won't reappear.

Comment: UPDATE: After a month no problem appeared. So the timeout setting in JMeter really solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a default time out setting in Jmeter properties file, see below:(Jmeter version 2.6.11)

```
# Following properties apply to both Commons and Apache HttpClient

# set the socket timeout (or use the parameter http.socket.timeout)
# Value is in milliseconds
httpclient.timeout=60000
# 0 == no timeout
```